# Stream video android-android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, streaming

I would like to stream a video between two android devices (android-android). There wouldn't be any server, so the streaming has to be direct between devices. Devices would be in the same network so they could communicate via WiFi.

I've tried using `MediaRecorder` - `MediaPlayer` via sockets, but I've received many exceptions.
I also looked for library, but I just want to stream a video between two devices directly.

Any solutions?

Comment: The best option was to use media recorder and media player, what except ions u r getting

Comment: @lib4
I'm getting `IllegalStateException` at `MediaRecorder.start()`
There is the sample code: https://pastebin.com/Hrh5aCkW

Comment: Although i have not done this I have done something very similar. Please check my blog post http://cagneymoreau.com/stream-video-android/

Answer (score 1):

If your video if for real time communication, e.g. a web chat or sharing some CCTV in real time with minimal delay then a real time video communication approach like WebRTC would be one additional possibility - this type of approach prioritises low latency over quality to ensure minimum delay. See here for Android WebRTC documentation:

- https://webrtc.org/native-code/android/

If the requirement is just to allow one device act as a server for non-real time videos then the easiest approach may be to use one of the available HTTP server libraries or apps to allow one device act as a server that the other one can simply connect to via a browser or player. An example Android HTTP server that seems to get good reviews is:

- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ubi.common.http.server&hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately, WebRTC won't work as the OP wants a serverless solution. Unless one of the devices will also work as a signaling server.

Comment: It sounds like you do need real time? There are some server less WebRTC solutions- basically they just use direct communications to exchange the end point address - e.g. https://github.com/cjb/serverless-webrtc